# Exit the script if the string if found

Tags: bash, unix, build, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to run 2 build commands. One of them is below. The condition is, if it finds the string "Error" on first build, it has to exit from the loop and shouldn't run anymore but if it doesn't it has to run the other build command that is ./v post-build. I have got the following but I think something is missing.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/logs
./v pre-build > test_file
File=test_file
value=$(grep -c Error $File )
if [ $value -eq 1 ]
then
echo "It's available"
else
./v post-build > test_file1
fi
```

Comment: There is no loop here. You can use `grep -q` and check the exit status

Comment: When I test with grep -q I get an error.

Comment: @james, keep in mind that the `if` condition is actually a *command* -- `[` is a command. The shell branches based on the exit status of that command. You want: `if grep -q Error "$File"; then ...`

Comment: @glennjackman 
line 5: if grep -q: command not found.  I kept getting this error that's why I changed my script.

Comment: what a weird error. That indicates to me that your editor is funky (spaces aren't plain ascii spaces) or you have quotes in strange places. You'll need to show your updated code.

Comment: @glennjackman This was my script. 
#!/bin/bash
File=test_file 
if grep -q Error "$File";
then
echo "It's available"
else
echo "Not available"
fi

Comment: assuming there are newlines in the obvious places, I don't see anything odd there. Try `od -c scriptname` to see if there are strange characters there.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need the output saved for post processing, there's no need to generate the intermediate files.  And your script can be as simple as:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/logs
./v pre-build | grep -q Error && exit 1
./v post-build
```

If you want to keep the intermediate files, just use `tee`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/logs
./v pre-build | tee test_file | grep -q Error && exit 1
./v post-build > test_file1
```

This removes the output "It's available", instead returning a failure when pre-build generates an error.  If you have control of `v`, you should have it also return an error rather than generating a string in its output, since you could then make the script as simple as:

```
./v pre-build && ./v post-build
```

(In that line, the `&&` short circuits, so that post-build only runs if pre-build succeeds.)

Comment: Your first one without tee is good except I had to put -c not -q. I always got error with -q, I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for **1** occurrence of the word Error.

I suggest you check if there are one or more instead:

```
   if [ $value -eq 1 ]
   # change to:
   if [ $value -gt 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If any occurence of Error can be found, you can test silently with grep like this:

```
!/bin/bash

cd /etc/logs

./v pre-build > test_file
grep -q "Error" test_file

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "It's available"
else
    ./v post-build > test_file1
fi
```